# Python decimal custom context

Tags: python, decimal, contextmanager

The context manager `decimal.localcontext` apparently is ignored when used inside another context. The following example illustrates this (Python 2.7):

```
from decimal import Decimal, Context, localcontext
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def precision_context(precision):
    yield localcontext(Context(prec=precision))

PRECISION=4
SMALL_NUMBER=Decimal('0.0001')

with localcontext(Context(prec=PRECISION)):
    # This is working as it should
    print SMALL_NUMBER + 1 # prints 1.000

with precision_context(PRECISION):
    # But this is not
    print SMALL_NUMBER + 1 # prints 1.0001
```

Why this happens, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because you don't actually enter the context manager (invoke the `__enter__` method). Nothing calls `localcontext(Context(prec=precision)).__enter__` because

```
with precision_context(PRECISION):
```

only enters the  `precision_context` context manager.

You can solve the problem by adding another `with` statement:

```
with precision_context(PRECISION) as ctx:
    # Enter `localcontext(Context(prec=precision))`
    with ctx:
        print(SMALL_NUMBER + 1) # prints 1.000
```

Comment: Great, thanks. I just put this code inside the `precision_context` function.